# Execute function with arguments listed in text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file (note - first 3 lines are blank) which has function with arguments value specified as shown below.

Text File:

```
Function_1  <arguments_1>  <arguments_2> <arguments_3> <arguments_4> 
Function_2  <arguments_1>  <arguments_2> <arguments_3> <arguments_4> 
Function_3  <arguments_1>  <arguments_2> <arguments_3> <arguments_4>
```

In a Shell script, I have the function definition.

Requirement is to read the content (i.e. Function with argument value) from 4th line available in the text file and exec the function present in shell script.

Shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
logfile=Execution_$now.log
exec 2>&1 | tee $logfile
Text_File = <path> 
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
done < "$Text_File"

Function_1()
{
  exec &> $1_$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M").log
  Change=$1
  Command=$2
  if [[ $Command == "get" ]];
    then Command_1="getfacl"
  elif [[ $Command == "set" ]];
    then Command_1="setfacl"
  fi

  Tag=$3
  if [[ -z "$Tag" ]];
    then Tag=""
    else Tag="-$Tag"
  fi
echo " "
echo "#############"
echo "Test Script"
echo "#############"
echo "Simply testing the script execution"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either source the text file:

```sh
. '/path/to/file'
```

or

```sh
source '/path/to/file'
```

Or read your file as an array, so each command and arguments are properly split by the `IFS` environment variable.

```sh
text_file='/path/to/file'
declare -a command_and_args_array
while read -r -a command_and_args_array # Read a command with arguments line
do
  "${command_and_args_array[@]}" # Execute the command with its arguments
done < "$text_file"
```

Comment: Im getting an the error as  - line 1: Function_1: command not found

Comment: @user78873 You need to execute the function definition — the `Function_1() {…` part — *before* the `source` command or loop that reads the file and uses the functions.

Comment: @Lea Gris & Gordon Davisson : Thanks for your help and feedback. Also im trying to print the echo statements in both console and trying to write it in a log file. i use the command  exec 2>&1 | tee $logfile but echo statement is getting printed in console alone and log file is empty. can you please suggest your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `declare -f some_function` to see if it exists before trying to call it:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    cat <<EOT
Usage: ${0##*/} text-file1 | - [text-file2 ...]
    Read function calls with parameters from text files or - for stdin.
    Run the function with its parameters if the function exists.
EOT
}

test "${#}" -eq 0 && {
    usage
    exit
}

Function_1() {
    # add logging, etc. here
    echo "\${@}: ${@}"
}

while read -r line; do
    # assign positional parameters to the contents of $line
    set -- $line

    # call function with new positional parameters if the function exists
    declare -f "$1" > /dev/null && "${@}"
done < <(cat "${@}")
```

Checking if the function exists adds some protection from accidentally running arbitrary commands. This also results in blank lines being skipped and lines with unsupported functions that are not defined in the master script.

Comment: I think you have understood my requirements differently. I have a text file with function name and arguments specified. I am passing the text file as a argument to my master script. Master script should read the text file line by line and execute the function definition available in it.

Comment: The function is called with arguments from the text file at the end of the line which starts with declare, but only if the function exists in the master script. I can update my answer to support passing the text file path as an argument.